# ERROR in flash (1023: Incompatible override. AND 1021: Duplicate function definition.)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Can someone help me to fix the error:

> (1023: Incompatible override. AND 1021: Duplicate function definition)

I'm new to **Flash** and **Action Script 3** so I really dont know how to fix this.

I'm creating a game which goes like this:
If I press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, the 'pamato' should go where the 'mouse2' is. It should follow the direction of mouse2. It must also have a friction and speed.

The source of the two errors is in the function speed.

Here is the code I made so far...

```
var sb:Number = 0;
var friction:Number = 0.0085;
var speed:Number = .002;
var path:Shape = new Shape();
addChild(path);

pamato.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, t_startDrag);
pamato.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, t_stopDrag);
position.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, b_position);
mouse.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, drawPath);
speedBar.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, speed);
pamato.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moving);

// dragging the pamato to its position
function t_startDrag(event:Event):void 
{
     pamato.startDrag();
}

function t_stopDrag(event:Event):void 
{
     pamato.stopDrag();

     if(pamato.hitTestObject(circle))
     {
         pamato.x = 605;
         pamato.y = 570;
     }
}

// position button
function b_position(event:Event):void 
{
     mouse.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, cursor)
     {
            function cursor(e:Event):void
        {
            mouse.alpha = 9;
            mouse.x = mouseX;
            mouse.y = mouseY;
        }
     }
}

// path && mouse2
function drawPath(event:Event):void 
{
     mouse2.x = mouse.x;
     mouse2.y = mouse.y;
     mouse2.alpha = 10;

     path.graphics.clear();
     path.graphics.lineStyle(1,0xFFFFFF,100);
     path.graphics.moveTo(pamato.x, pamato.y); 
     path.graphics.lineTo(mouse2.x, mouse2.y);
}

// speed bar
function speed(event:Event):void
{
     speedBar.scaleX = sb;

     stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, myKeyDown)
     {
         function myKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void
         {  
             if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE)
             {
                  sb += .0005;

                 if (sb > 1)
                 {
                     sb = 0;
                 }
              } 
         }   
      } 
}

// moving the pamato
function moving(event:Event):void
{
     stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, enterKey)
     {
             if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER)
             {
                 var myRadians:Number = Math.atan2(mouse2.y-pamato.y, mouse2.x-pamato.x);
                 var myDegrees:Number = Math.round((myRadians*180/Math.PI));
                 var yChange:Number = Math.round(mouse2.y-pamato.y);
                 var xChange:Number = Math.round(mouse2.y-pamato.y);
                 var yMove:Number = Math.round(yChange/20);
                 var xMove:Number = Math.round(xChange/20);
                 var yspeed:Number = yspeed + yMove;
                 var xspeed:Number = xspeed + xMove;

                 removeChild(holder);
                 mouse2.alpha = 0;
                 mouse.alpha = 0;
                 sb = 0;
             }

      }

     xspeed *= friction;
     yspeed *= friction;
     y += yspeed;
     x += xspeed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you're adding event listeners is wrong. Either call a specific function like this:

```
function speed(event:Event):void
{
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, this._onKeyDown );
}

private function _onKeyDown( e:KeyboardEvent ):void
{
    // do something
}
```

Or an anonymous function like this:

```
function speed( event:Event ):void
{
    stage.addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, function( e:KeyboardEvent )
        {
            // this is the function block for the anon function
            // do something
        } ); // end of add listener
}
```

Of the two, the first version is the best way to do it, as it allows you to remove the event listener when you're finished with it (not removing event listeners means that objects can't be garbage collected, meaning memory leak)

If you still have problems, can you post the full error (should have the error text, and the line where the problem is)

Comment: i had another error (1013: The private attribute may be used only on class property definitions.) here's my modified code: 

// speed bar
function speed(event:Event):void
{
 speedBar.scaleX = sb;
  
 stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, this._onKeyDown);
}

private function _onKeyDown( e:KeyboardEvent ):void
{ 
 if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE)
 {
  sb += .0005;
    
  if (sb > 1)
  {
   sb = 0;
  }
 }
}

i think, i done it wrong... :(
also, can you check the FUNCTION MOVING..? because i think, that's the source of the problem. the errors appeared when i added that function....

Comment: i originally made that game in AS2 but when i tried to convert it to AS3..its a mess! 

its much easier when i made that game in AS2...

Comment: this is the code again.. 
`// speed bar
      function speed(event:Event):void
      {
      speedBar.scaleX = sb;
   
       stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, this._onKeyDown);
      }

      private function _onKeyDown( e:KeyboardEvent ):void
      { 
      if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE)
      {
       sb += .0005;
    
       if (sb > 1)
        {
        sb = 0;
        }
       }
      }`

Comment: is all this code inside a class, or just copied into an .as file? If it's in a class, you can use `public`, `private`, and `protected` to control access to variable and functions etc. In the example I gave you, I was assuming it was in a class, so if it's not just remove the `private` definition from the `_onKeyDown` function declaration.

Comment: for the function `moving()`, again you're declaring your `addEventListener()` wrong. Just follow the same syntax as the answer